# When a filesystem copies a folder and its contents recursively, is it done using DFS or BFS?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Apologies in advance if this question doesn't belong here, but it was a random thought I had while waiting for large folders to copy over to my external hard drive. When folders are copied from one place to another, is copying done via DFS (i.e. it goes as deep as it can for each subfolder at a time) or BFS (it searches by "layer")?

I don't know much about how operating systems work and I can't seem to find anything on Google because DFS and BFS trigger vastly different types of questions unrelated to this question.

Follow up questions: does it depend on the filesystem and/or OS at all? Why was one chosen over the other?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is very broad and there's basically no "correct" answer, therefore [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)... there are many file systems out there and "searching" is not really applicable, but from experience basically it's usually(?) DF"S". Create all the folders down to the first file, copy that, copy the rest of the files at that leaf, then back up a level and do the next one. I'd be curious to hear of a FS where all the top-level files and folders are created, then populated one at a time like a card dealer--I haven't seen this.

Comment: Sorry about being off-topic, and thanks for the welcome! I definitely made a bad assumption in thinking that most filesystems are similar (which I feel like are probably not). Thank you anyway for your insight though!

Comment: @YoungLee maybe revise your question and ask for a specific filesystem (or two?) and it wouldn't be off topic anymore :D

Answer (score 1):

it certainly depends on the OS! I think every OS prefers DFS in terms of less memory consumption and easier to implement than BFS; you can follow this link: [algorithm for directory structure scanning](https://superuser.com/questions/194374/breadth-first-option-in-the-linux-find-utility)

but not sure, is there any such common implementation for scanning!